# Как присвоить значение класса в CSS для вида на определенной странице?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, классы

Добрый день. Как присвоить значение класса в CSS для перехода на определенную страницу?

```
.company { 
    background: url(images/menu/0001.png) no-repeat;  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px; 
    height: 180px; 
}
.company:hover { 
    background: url(images/menu/0001hover.png) no-repeat; 
    width: 140px; 
    height: 180px; 
}
.company[href="company"] {
    background: url(images/menu/0001hover.png) no-repeat; 
    width: 140px; 
    height: 180px; 
}
```

т.е. при переходе на страницу "company" и только на неё на сайте, он обретал вид как на последнем элементе кода. Последний элемент в коде не работает, либо я его не так написал

Comment: HTML ссылки на страницу "company" добавьте

Comment: последний класс применяется к элементу у которого есть атрибут `href` значение которого `company`. А вы знаете что вы привели три одинаковых класса?

Comment: @Komdosh примерно как будет выглядеть код?

Comment: @Alex эм, очевидно <a class="company" href="/company">Компания</a>

Comment: @Komdosh, нет не так

Comment: @Grundy, а как?

Comment: @Komdosh, `href="company"`

Comment: @Grundy, а, тупанул

Comment: @Grundy я уже понял, что к элементу, а к конкретной странице (в данном случае /company) ?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял из вопроса Вы хотите подменить класс при посещении определенной страницы?
Для решения Вашей задачи один только CSS не подойдет.Тут потребуеться дополнение в виде JS или PHP или JSP  etc...Все вышеперечисленные языки нужны лиш затем что бы динамически определить URL страницы...Дальше логика выходит из Ваших условий окружения то-ли вы создадите некую срытую переменную и силами [CSS Conditional Rules](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/#at-supports) будете изменять править...Можете подключить библиотеку динамической СSS типа [Less](http://lesscss.org/) к примеру...К слову эта библиотека  то же спарка JS и СSS

Answer (score 0):

Для FF можно воспользоваться [@document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@document)

```
@document url(http://www.w3.org/),
               url-prefix(http://www.w3.org/Style/),
               domain(mozilla.org),
               regexp("https:.*")
{
  /* CSS rules here apply to:
     - The page "http://www.w3.org/".
     - Any page whose URL begins with "http://www.w3.org/Style/"
     - Any page whose URL's host is "mozilla.org" or ends with
       ".mozilla.org"
     - Any page whose URL starts with "https:" */

  /* make the above-mentioned pages really ugly */
  body {
    color: purple;
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Присваивайте тегу `body` или любому другому, необходимому вам, класс `company` в случае, если вы находитесь на странице со слагом `company`. Для вордпресс это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<body class="<?php echo is_page('company') ? 'company' : ''; ?>">
```

`is_page()` в качестве аргумента может принимать как слаг, так и `id` страницы.